How to expand data where specific condition is met in Pandas Python?
I have a pandas dataframe where some of the rows data is ending with Numbers and I need to split the ending numbers in those rows and shift only those to the right columns.
Below is a sample df:
check_df = pd.DataFrame({
             'Test': ["Absolute Neutrophil Count","Absolute Lymphocyte Count 2.9","Absolute Neutrophil Count"],
             'Result1': [6.56,2.8,5.5],
             'Result2': [5.14,2.6,4.8],
             'Result3': [4.69,"10~9/L",5.2],
             'Unit': ["10~9/L","1.0-3.0","10~9/L"],
             'Range': ["4.0-10.0",None,"4.0-10.0"]                      
             }) 

check_df


                Test             Result1    Result2 Result3 Unit      Range
0   Absolute Neutrophil Count       6.56    5.14    4.69    10~9/L    4.0-10.0
1   Absolute Lymphocyte Count 2.9   2.80    2.60    10~9/L  1.0-3.0   None
2   Absolute Neutrophil Count       5.50    4.80    5.2     10~9/L    4.0-10.0

I have tried below regex code to figure out "Test" rows that are ending with Numbers:
check_df.iloc[:,0].str.contains(r'\d+$')

Desired Result:
                Test             Result1    Result2 Result3 Unit      Range
0   Absolute Neutrophil Count       6.56    5.14    4.69    10~9/L    4.0-10.0
1   Absolute Lymphocyte Count        2.9    2.80    2.60    10~9/L    1.0-3.0
2   Absolute Neutrophil Count       5.50    4.80    5.2     10~9/L    4.0-10.0

Doubt:
But I am not sure how to split only those rows based on index or other method so that all the rows/ columns data can be in proper aligned data table format.
Update to Answer:


The best would be to avoid the error in the first place by correctly reading your input.
That said you could extract the digits and identify the incorrect rows with notna, then shift and update:
tmp = check_df.iloc[:,0].str.extract(r'^(.*?)\s*(\d\.?\d*)?$')

out = check_df.copy()
out.update(check_df.assign(Test=tmp[1]).loc[tmp[1].notna()].shift(axis=1))

out['Test'] = tmp[0]

Output:
                        Test Result1  Result2 Result3    Unit     Range
0  Absolute Neutrophil Count    6.56     5.14    4.69  10~9/L  4.0-10.0
1  Absolute Lymphocyte Count     2.9     2.80     2.6  10~9/L   1.0-3.0
2  Absolute Neutrophil Count     5.5     4.80     5.2  10~9/L  4.0-10.0

Note that this won't magically fix the dtypes.
Another approach might be to export to CSV, fix the first column with a regex and reimport the data:
import re
from io import StringIO

s = check_df.to_csv(index=False)

out = pd.read_csv(StringIO(re.sub(r'(\n[\w\s]+?)\s*(\d+\.\d*)(,[^\n]+),(\n|$)',
                                  r'\1,\2\3\4', s)))

regex demo
Output and intermediates:
# out
                        Test  Result1  Result2  Result3    Unit     Range
0  Absolute Neutrophil Count     6.56     5.14     4.69  10~9/L  4.0-10.0
1  Absolute Lymphocyte Count     2.90     2.80     2.60  10~9/L   1.0-3.0
2  Absolute Neutrophil Count     5.50     4.80     5.20  10~9/L  4.0-10.0

# out.dtypes
Test        object
Result1    float64
Result2    float64
Result3    float64
Unit        object
Range       object
dtype: object

# s
Test,Result1,Result2,Result3,Unit,Range
Absolute Neutrophil Count,6.56,5.14,4.69,10~9/L,4.0-10.0
Absolute Lymphocyte Count 2.9,2.8,2.6,10~9/L,1.0-3.0,
Absolute Neutrophil Count,5.5,4.8,5.2,10~9/L,4.0-10.0

# fixed CSV
Test,Result1,Result2,Result3,Unit,Range
Absolute Neutrophil Count,6.56,5.14,4.69,10~9/L,4.0-10.0
Absolute Lymphocyte Count,2.9,2.8,2.6,10~9/L,1.0-3.0
Absolute Neutrophil Count,5.5,4.8,5.2,10~9/L,4.0-10.0


Thanks for showing multiple ways and adding explanation to them. Appreciate your help !!

@ViSa you're welcome, glad it helped. As said, it would be even better to fix the issue prior to importing the data.

In 2nd method of csv I am still getting 2.9 in the Test column Absolute Lymphocyte Count 2.9,2.8,2.6,10~9/L,1.0-3.0, in the out . Are you sure you you are getting it separated your out ?

Yes, I just tested again with your DataFrame constructor and this works fine. See for yourself as a one-liner: pd.read_csv(StringIO(re.sub(r'(\n[\w\s]+?)\s*(\d+\.\d*)(,[^\n]+),(\n|$)', r'\1,\2\3\4', pd.DataFrame({'Test': ["Absolute Neutrophil Count","Absolute Lymphocyte Count 2.9","Absolute Neutrophil Count"], 'Result1': [6.56,2.8,5.5], 'Result2': [5.14,2.6,4.8], 'Result3': [4.69,"10~9/L",5.2], 'Unit': ["10~9/L","1.0-3.0","10~9/L"], 'Range': ["4.0-10.0",None,"4.0-10.0"]}).to_csv(index=False))))

That's strange because I am still getting fields not separated. I have updated the post with the screenshot of the code & output. But its ok I will use the 1st approach as that is working fine for me.
